# Parse a string dynamically in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string-parsing

I have a hashmap with just two keys.
One key, value is having a pattern like this -

```
"flownamewkf1_somethingwkf2_something.." => 1"
```

The second key, value has pattern like this -

```
"some_name" => "group_name"
```

Now i want to create a new string in this way:

```
make-deployment-group --flowname/wkf1_something --flowname/wkf2_something group_name
```

Sometimes flowname can have only one wkf name and then the first key,value will be `"flownamewkf1_something" => 1"`  and the string should be

```
make-deployment-group --flowname/wkf1_something group_name
```

So, I need to dynamically generate the string based on number of wkf, the flowname has and add the `group_name` at the end and make-deployment-group at the beginning and the folder and wkf names in the middle

I tried `string.partition(/wkf/)` but the splits the string into three parts flowname, wkf, rest of part

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are asking. But maybe you can take this and run with it.

```
1.8.7 :049 > flowname, *wkf = "flownamewkf1_somethingwkf2_something".split(/wkf/)
 => ["flowname", "1_something", "2_something"] 
1.8.7 :050 > params = wkf.collect{|w| "--#{flowname}/wkf#{w}"}
 => ["--flowname/wkf1_something", "--flowname/wkf2_something"] 
1.8.7 :052 >   "make-deployment-group #{params.join(' ')}"
 => "make-deployment-group --flowname/wkf_something--flowname/wkf_something"
```

Then you can tack on that group_name.